# reactのuseContextについて

Tags: javascript, reactjs

特に決まったシチュエーションも無いため画像なども添付することができないのですが、ご了承下さい。

react初心者ではありますが、コードのコンポーネントに分割した際に、それぞれのコンポーネントを連携させていく作業が複雑で訳が分からない。（例えば、constで新たな関数を定義するときなど）
Udemyのreact入門編で学習をしているのですがなかなか心が折れてしまいます。
そこで何か、アドバイスや勉強法、学習ツールがあれば教えていただきたいです。